# SQL (oracle): is there an equivalent to substr for numeric fields?

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

To retrieve characters between position X and Y *from a string* in oracle sql I can

```
substr(string_var, X, Y)
```

What if I need to get the digits from a number between position X and Y?  (i.e. if I want the third and fourth digits in the number 123456 = 34)

I know I can

```
substr(to_char(numeric_var), X, Y)
```

But what if I need the output to be treated as a number? Do I have to do

```
to_number(substr(to_char(numeric_var), X, Y))
```

Or is there an equivalent to substr for numeric fields?

Comment: There is not a `substr` equivalent function for numbers.

Comment: What would you expect for `substr(123.45, 3, 4)`?  Are we assuming integer only?

Comment: You could create a function for it

Comment: No, there's not. (Numbers don't contain partial digits; they're numbers.) You'd have to establish a numeric range (`WHERE numeric_var BETWEEN 123400 AND 123499`, for instance), or convert to a string and back.

Comment: In my use case its integer only. but, I was just hoping there was a shorthand for to_number(substr(to_char(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle will do the type conversion for you:

```
with foo(bar) as 
 (select 123456 from dual union
  select 654321 from dual union
  select 434343 from dual)
select substr(bar,3,2),
       substr(bar,3,2) + 10
from foo;

SUBSTR(BAR,3,2)  SUBSTR(BAR,3,2)+10
---------------  ------------------
34               44
43               53
43               53
```

Comment: I don't know if I should be amazed or appalled.

Comment: This approach has the problem that its behaviour will change depending on the session's NLS settings. Don't rely on implicit type conversion.